# Creating UILabels within dynamic TableViewCells using Swift and Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard

So I'm trying to create UILabels within a dynamic TableView, and set up a subclass UITableViewCell, but when I build my project, the UILabels don't display any text.

**GamesFeedCell**

```
import UIKit

class GamesFeedCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var game1Name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var game2Name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var score1: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var score2: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization codea
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

**GamesFeedViewController**

```
import UIKit

class GamesFeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "GamesFeedCell", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle()), forCellReuseIdentifier: "gamesFeedCell")
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @available(iOS 2.0, *)
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell: GamesFeedCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("gamesFeedCell") as! GamesFeedCell

        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = GamesFeedCell()
        }

        (cell as GamesFeedCell).game1Name.text = "game1"
        (cell as GamesFeedCell).game2Name.text = "game2"
        (cell as GamesFeedCell).score1.text = "score1"
        (cell as GamesFeedCell).score2.text = "score2"

        return cell!
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using prototype cells in a storyboard then you don't need the `registerNib`. Also, `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` won't ever return nil. Have you set your delegate & datasource?  Set breakpoints and verify that `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is being called. You haven't declared you view controller to be `UITableViewDatasource`, so I suspect you haven't set the view controller as your table datasource

Comment: You also don't need the `: GameFeedCell` where you declare `var cell`. Swift can infer the type from the downcast

Comment: Paulw11, you should submit this as an answer.  Too many people make these mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I would verify two things:

1. `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is actually returning an instance of `GamesFeedCell` - and if not, make sure the identifier matches what is in Interface Builder for the cell
2. The IBOutlets for the `UILabel`s are hooked up.

I also don't think this code is necessary, and likely causing a bug, because if `cell` does happen to be `nil` it will be `init`'d normally and thus nothing that you setup in the Dynamic Prototype from Interface Builder will be present.  My suggestion: delete this code (which may expose the bug that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` isn't actually dequeueing anything since the identifier is wrong.

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = GamesFeedCell()
}
```